# Android HTTP Request Encoding

Tags: java, android, encoding, utf-8, httprequest

I want to do a HTTPRequest in my Android App, using the following Code:

```
BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI("http://www.example.de/example.php"));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();
        String page = sb.toString();

        System.out.println(page);
        return page;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
   }
```

The webpage I'm calling is a php Script which returns a string. My problem is that the the special Characters (ä,ü,ö,€ etc.) are showed as a Question mark with a box. How can I get these characters?

I think it's a problem with the encoding (German App -> UTF-8?).

Comment: Can you verify the content in from browser if the correct right character encoding is returning.

Comment: My Browser is showing the content correct.

Comment: Please check by setting,  request.setHeader("Content-type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");.

Comment: Did it, but dont work... My Browser says the page is encoded to Cp1252 (Windows-1252).

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try to set encoding when displaying into the console. Something characters are correctly returned from the server but fails to display in the console.

```
String page = sb.toString();
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
out.println(page);
```

Comment: No, that don't works :( I get the Questionmarks in the Console, too.

Comment: Make sure your server returns "UTF-8" character set

Answer (score 0):

I have played around with your code, against `http://www.google.de`.

I was able to "hack" something, not sure it's the most elegant solution though.

After the line:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

... I've added:

```
HttpEntity e = response.getEntity();
Header ct = e.getContentType();
HeaderElement[] he = ct.getElements();
if (
    he.length > 0 
        && he[0].getParameters().length > 0
        && he[0].getParameter(0) != null 
        && he[0].getParameter(0).getName().equals("charset")
    ) {
    String charset = he[0].getParameter(0).getValue();
    // with google.de, will print ISO latin ("ISO-8859-1")
    Log.d("com.example.test", charset);
}
```

... then you can add the charset representation, or its Java equivalent as a second argument of your `InputStreamReader` constructor call:

```
in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
        response.getEntity().getContent(), 
        charset != null ? charset : "UTF-8"
);
```

Let me know if that works out for you.

Also note that in order to check Java charset equivalences, you could use `Charset.forName(String charsetName)` and catch the relevant `Exception`s (and then revert to `Charset.defaultCharset()` or *UTF-8*, etc. in your `catch` statement).

Comment: @user2174738 I edited my answer to check on the `NameValuePair` array returned by `he[0]`, which was likely to cause your `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. However your case means that there are probably no header elements in your response's entity. In which case, I suppose it might be really hard to detect the response's encoding. You'll have to make sure which encoding it is, and add it as before, as an argument to the initialization of your `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: @user2174738 ... and since you say in the question comments your web page encodes in ANSI, use that as a charset encoding in your `InputStreamReader` argument list.